# Hermitian matrix versus unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix):

> In linear algebra, a complex square matrix $U$ is unitary if its conjugate transpose $U^*$ is also its inverse, that is, if $U^{*} U = U U^{*}=I,$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. In physics, especially in quantum mechanics, the Hermitian adjoint of a matrix is denoted by a dagger ($\dagger$) and the equation above becomes $U^{\dagger} U = U U^{\dagger }=I.$

Are the terms "Hermitian  matrix" and "unitary matrix" one and the same? If not, how are they different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hermitian Matrix $H$ has $H = H^\dagger \neq I$, where for a unitary matrix $U$ you have $U^\dagger = U^{-1}\neq U$.

They are the complex analogous to "symmetrical" and "orthogonal"